# invite friends to facebook app - android, no invitations sent

Tags: android, facebook

I have created a facebook event with my android coding and now I want to invite friends to it.
Below is my code to invite friends:

```
  private void inviteFriends()
    {
        try
        {   
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("title", "invite friends");
            params.putString("message", "come join us!");
            facebook.dialog(this, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {}

                public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject eventResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        //event_id = event.getString("id");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Event Response => "+eventResponse);
                        Log.w("myapp", friends);

                       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Event Created!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

The code works up to selecting friends, the title and message comes with the friend list. I can send the invitation but no notifications are sent to selected people.

Please tell me what needs to be done. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[image: see] this image.

Have you turned on the App omn Facebbok Tab in your app developer setting like this.
If don't then it will not sent notification to your friends.